# How to reference another java file from within Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Inside my GameActivity.java I have a link to a website, which is under a

```
public void gotoWebsite() {
//link to site here
}
```

however, I would like to refer to this from a TitleLayer.java class file.

For example, on that TitleLayer.java, there is a button, which is also a public void, how can I place a link to refer to the 'gotoWebsite' link that already exists in GameActivity.java?

Comment: Are you saying you want to call this gotoWebsite() method from your GameActivity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a few ways:

1 - Add a Constructor to GameActivity and create a new instance of GameActivity inside TittleLayer or pass the GameActivity object to your TitleLayer class.

2 - Make the goToWebsite static and reference it using `GameActivity.goToWebsite()` from any other file.

Comment: Number 2 sounds the way to go, how would I go about making that goToWebsite static in GameActivity.java?

Comment: just add static before void...
`public static void goToWebsite() {
 // Stuff happens here.
}`